# simplifying a nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var someUglyObject = 
{
    "1-1" : {foo1: "foo1-1Value", bar1: "bar1-1value"},
    "1-2" : {foo2: "foo1-2Value", bar2: "bar1-2value"},
    "2-1" : {foo2: "foo2-1Value", bar2: "bar2-1value"},
    "2-2" : {foo2: "foo2-2Value", bar2: "bar2-2value"}
}
```

I need to simplify the nested object above and convert into a simpler object after some processing (concatenation) like below:

```
var myObj = { 
             "1": { propsTogether : "foo1-1Valuebar1-1valuefoo1-2Valuebar1-2value"},
             "2": { propsTogether : "foo2-1Valuebar2-1valuefoo2-2Valuebar2-2value" }
        }
```

My plan is to interate through the keys like this, but not sure how to group the props together based on the first char of the key , i.e. for a key with value of '2-1' - 2 should be the new key.

```
var myObj= {};
Object.keys(someUglyObject).forEach(function(key) {

}
```

Comment: Isn't the second object much uglier than the first (they're both not pretty, but the second is completely unreadable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` and `reudce`

Here idea is

- First get the keys out of object.
- Sort them    // Object don't have order
- Now split key on `-` and use `first element` as key on `op` object.
- Use object.values and join them in desired format and place it on respective key

```js
var obj = {'1-1' : {foo1: "foo1-1Value", bar1: "bar1-1value"},'1-2' : {foo2: "foo1-2Value", bar2: "bar1-2value"},'2-1' : {foo2: "foo2-1Value", bar2: "bar2-1value"},'2-2' : {foo2: "foo2-2Value", bar2: "bar2-2value"}}


let op = Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let key = inp.split('-',1)[0]
  op[key] = op[key] || {props:''}
  op[key].props = op[key].props + Object.values(obj[inp]).join('')
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Looks beautiful! Thank you for the explanation!!

Comment: @AJSwift always happy to help :)

Comment: how do I simply extract the nested objects like `{1 : { {foo1: "foo1-1Value", bar1: "bar1-1value"}, {foo2: "foo1-2Value", bar2: "bar1-2value"}}, 2:  {  {..}, {..} }`  ?

Comment: @AJSwift that's not a valid format you need to have `key:value` pair in JSON, `1 : { {foo1: "foo1-1Value", ` this is not.